# How to verify login functionality with multiple credentials if Both need to run in every @Test in a same Class[In Maven POM Selenium project]

Tags: java, maven, selenium-webdriver

I want to Run Test in a same class with two credentials, and both are in same `TestRunner` class, I want to declare in `@Beforemethod` class so that no need to write same code in Every `@Test`.

Comment: You need to better describe what you are doing now and what you want to accomplish. As it is written, it's not clear what you are trying to do. Post some example code.

Answer (score 1):

If I understood, You want to run same test twice, but with different credentials.

If this is the case use dataProvider:

```
@DataProvider(name="login")
    public Object[][] getData() {
        return new Object[][] {
            {"test2@test.com", "test",false},
            {"test@test.com", "abcabc",true}
        };
    }
```

and here is method how to call it.

```
@Test(dataProvider="login")
public void testLogin(String usernameEmail, String password,boolean flag) throws InterruptedException {

  if(flag){
      Assert.assertTrue(!errorMessage.isDisplayed());
  }else{
      Assert.assertTrue(errorMessage.isDisplayed());
  }
}
```

Hope I understood and it would help You,

Updated answer with pseudo code of a sort, so You could create method without annotation just simple method inside test class or in different one, depending on Your logic, and provide parameter to that method within test methods here is example:

Don't know how You data is set in @BeforeMethod, because there is no code example, but here is something:

```
@Test
public void testLogin_1(){
    login(email, password)
}

@Test
public void testLogin_2(){
    login(email2, password2)
}


private void login(String email, String password){
   inputEmail(email);
   inputPassword(password);
   clickSubmit();

   Assert.assertEquals();
   // do some asserts so if You want to assert some error cases.
}
```

Hope this helps,

Comment: Yes Right, I want to Run Same test twice, But My doubt is whr to pass the value , earlier i was keeping login credentials in @BeforeTest but now I have to use with another credentials in same class, with another Test

Comment: Just use DataProvider, and test would execute as many times as many parameters You set in dataprovider, and other test could execute in "single instance". Hope code would help You

Comment: I want to pass two values means two credentials, but in separate Test in same class

Comment: public void testLogin(String usernameEmail, String password,boolean flag), This need to pass, but how use them, I am not getting

Comment: @HimanshuMidha : `public void testLogin(String usernameEmail, String password,boolean flag)` in this you should write your code for login.  Because it will run twice as per the current solution provided by Kovacic. Just keep driver initialization and URL in `@BeforeMethod`

Comment: @Kovacic : It's better if you write the **login** code inside `testLogin()` method. OP is getting confused with that , because he is keeping all his credentials in  `@BeforeMethod`

Comment: it is running twice but I want to run One credential in separate Test and another credential in separate Test, It is running in same test twice.. that i dont want, both credential i want to use in different test but same page

Comment: Here is updated answer if I got what You need. Try to add some example code to have better insight on what You need.

Comment: Change your `.assertTrue()` in `testLogin()` to `.assertEquals(flag, errorMessage.isDisplayed())` and remove the `if`. A data provider is the right way to go here. I would remove the second half of your answer until OP provides a better description of what he's done and what he wants. Your last `login()` method returns true but it's return type is void... you should remove `return true`.

Comment: Sure I agree with You @JeffC, as I mentioned this is just an lets say "pseudo code", Himanshu should connect the dots, I just provided means, not the complete answer. But Your absolutely right.